# How can I specify to use Linq ThenBy clause only when there is a tie?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, ienumerable

I have a linq query (not database-related) with OrderBy and ThenBy

```
var sortedList = unsortedList
                .OrderBy(foo => foo.Bar) //this property access is relatively fast
                .ThenBy(foo => foo.GetCurrentValue()) //this method execution is slow
```

getting `foo.Bar` is fast, but executing `foo.GetCurrentValue()` is very slow. The return value only matters if some members have equal Bar values, which happens rarely but important to be considered in case it happens. Is it possible to choose to only execute the ThenBy clause when it's necessary to tie-break in case of equal Bar values? (i.e. will not be executed if foo.Bar values are unique).

Also, actually Bar is also a bit slow, so it is preferred not to invoke it twice for the same object.

Comment: What are you doing that the `foo.Bar` call is slow? is Bar a large struct or is it the `Compare` operation that is slow?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no, I mean foo.Bar (the first criteria) is fast, it's foo.GetCurrentValue that is slow.

Comment: I was referring to the statement "*Also, actually Bar is also a bit slow, so it is preferred not to invoke it twice for the same object.*"

Comment: ah, I don't remember exactly. It's been one year, I don't even remember what specific application I found this issue in :) But I remember the code in the accepted answer worked well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit clumsy, but I'm sure it can be improved - maybe it won't be done in one linq statement, but it should work:

```
var sortedList2 = unsortedList
                .OrderBy(foo => foo.Bar)
                .GroupBy(foo => foo.Bar);

            var result = new List<Foo>();
            foreach (var s in sortedList2)
            {
                if (s.Count() > 1)
                {
                    var ordered = s
                        .OrderBy(el => el.GetCurrentValue());
                    result.AddRange(ordered);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.AddRange(s);
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE:** 
We can argue if that's an improvement, but it looks more concise at least:

```
var list3 = (from s in sortedList2
             let x = s.Count()
             select x == 1 
                    ? s.Select(el => el) 
                    : s.OrderBy(el => el.GetCurrentValue()))
             .SelectMany(n => n);
```

**UPDATE2:**

You can use `Skip(1).Any()` instead of `Count()` - this should avoid the enumeration of the whole sequence I guess.

Comment: +1, Not so fond of the `.Count()`. Since `s` needs to be enumerated anyway, you only add another enumeration. Sorting a list of one element doesn't take very long

Comment: Though, it really depends on the implementation of the sorter. Dunno ;) Does anyone know, if `GroupBy` takes advantage of the `IOrderedEnumerable`?

Comment: @skarmats - would using `Skip(1).Any()` instead of `Count()` be what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are not in a database, and you need a tight control over the sorting, you could use a single OrderBy with a custom IComparer that accesses only what it needs, and does not perform unnecessary evaluations.

Comment: But, if I do this, the `Compare` method might be caleld more than once for the same object, right? like the sort algorithm will try to compare A-B then A-C, A-D, etc., so probably A.Bar (the primary sort criteria) will be called more than once?

Comment: @LouisRhys This is correct, the compare will be called on the average `Log2(N)` times, but that is the same number as the `Bar` would be calculated without the custom comparer. If calculating a property takes long, you can always cache the result in a private variable, so that the number of invocations beyond `1` would not matter at all.

Comment: +1 the IComparer interface is very simple to implement, and you'll end up with a much cleaner solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = unsortedList
  .GroupBy(foo => foo.Bar)
  .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
  .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1).Any() ? g.OrderBy(foo => foo.GetCurrentValue()) : g);
```

This has the obvious downside of not returning `IOrderedEnumerable<Foo>`

Answer (score 0):

I changed Joanna Turban's solution and developed the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderByThenBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> orderBy, Func<TSource, TKey> thenBy)
{
    var sorted = source
        .Select(s => new Tuple<TSource, TKey>(s, orderBy(s)))
        .OrderBy(s => s.Item2)
        .GroupBy(s => s.Item2);

    var result = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (var s in sorted)
    {
        if (s.Count() > 1)
            result.AddRange(s.Select(p => p.Item1).OrderBy(thenBy));
        else
            result.Add(s.First().Item1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Its defined in the .NET framework's `Tuple` class, its only used in this method internally...

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
var sortedList = unsortedList.OrderBy(foo => foo.Bar);

if(some_Condition)
{ 
   sortedList = sortedList.OrderBy(foo => foo.GetCurrentValue()); 
}
```

Comment: where would the value of some_condition be from? and why is the list resorted by get current value? I want the getcurrentvalue to be used only to help sorting when there are two foos with the same bar value